How to 'delay' a link from triggering
I'm looking to achieve something like the header menu at https://www.mammut.com/uk/en
Whereby there is a slight 'delay' from triggering another link as the user moves to select a secondary menu item. Hence another link isn't made active when hovered as the user chooses a secondary link. Essentially what a CSS transition-delay would achieve.
I'm using Alpine js with Astro.
I'm setting the activeLinkIndex via @mouseEnter
<template x-for="(link, linkIndex) in links" :key="linkIndex">
  <a href="/" @mouseenter="linkEnter(linkIndex)">
    <p x-text="link.text"></p>
  </a>
</template>

linkEnter(index) {
  this.activeLinkIndex = index
},


And secondary links are then displayed via x-show based on the activeLinkIndex
<template x-for="(link, index) in link.links" :key="index">
  <ul x-show="activeLinkIndex === index">
    <template x-for="(sublink, sublinkIndex) in link.links" :key="sublinkIndex">
      <a href="/">
        <p x-text="sublink.text"></p>
      </a>
    </template>
  </ul>
</template>


I've tried using a setTimeout in LinkEnter, but each @mouseEnter is triggered.
I've also tried Alpine Modifiers: .debounce and .throttle unsuccessfully.
Any advice would be much appreciated.
